# Checking Statuses

Tags: sql, oracle

I am rather new to writing SQL scripts and would like some advice on the best way to check statuses.

I need to find all Delivery Areas that have at least one Delivery with a Status of 2 and check those same areas to see if any other deliveries for those areas have a status of 1, 3, or 4.

Here is what I have written currently...

```
SELECT 
  DR.AREA, 
  T.STTS_ID
FROM TASK T
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DLY_RTE_ASGMNT DRA
    ON T.TASK_ID = DRA.TASK_ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN DLY_RTE DR
    ON DR.DLY_RTE_ID = DRA.DLY_RTE_ID
WHERE 
  DR.AREA IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY DR.AREA
```

and here is the output that I get from it:

```
AREA   STTS_ID
000-ST     1
000-ST     3
000-ST     1
000-ST     1
000-ST     2
100        1
100        1
100        1
100        1
100        1
```

There is more data then what is shown above, but it illustrates what i get back.

What would be the best way to check each unique AREA to see if it contains a STTS_ID of 2 and also has a delivery that contains a STTS_ID  of 1, 3, or 4.

Coding samples are not necessarily what I am looking for here, although they would be appreciated...  I am more trying wrap my head around the most efficient way of going about the task...

Thank you in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-select the data with status 2 and make a standard inner JOIN.

E.g. pseudo-SQL:

```
select st134.area,st134.status
from (select area
      from mytable
      where status = 2) st2,
     mytable st134
where st134.area = st2.area
```

This should be the cleanest and the most performance efficient way to do that.

Comment: That gave me the direction I needed. Thanks Simon

Answer (score 0):

I have not got clear understanding on two diff status you are referring but I have separated out two. with good understanding in clause can be eliminated with exists clause.

```
with tab_stts2 as
(select * from task where status=2)
select   dra.area, tab_stts2.stts_id from tab_stts2, dly_rte_asgmnt dra, dly_rte dr
where tab_stts2.task_id = dra.task_id
and dra.dly_rte_id = dra.dly_rte_id
and (status table alias).status in (1,3,4);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query shows only areas containing task with status=2 and in separate columns presents number of tasks with statuses 1,3,4:

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f8f46/1)</sup>

```
select area, 
    count(case when stts_id = 1 then 1 end) st1, 
    count(case when stts_id = 3 then 1 end) st3, 
    count(case when stts_id = 4 then 1 end) st4
  from task 
    join dly_rte_asgmnt dra using (task_id) 
    join dly_rte using (dly_rte_id)
  group by area
  having count(case when stts_id = 2 then 1 end) > 0
```